# Restaurar perfil en W11 con USMT

Tags: windows, usercontrol, migracion

tengo el siguiente problema. En un equipo debo restaurar un perfil concreto de W11 a un estado inicial después de cada uso de ese mismo perfil. Con la herramienta USMT de Microsoft he hecho un backup del perfil en el estado inicial, pero a la hora de restaurar el perfil me encuentro con los siguientes problemas.

- Si el usuario, por ejemplo creó un archivo en escritorio al hacer el LoadState ese archivo permanece
- Si borro previamente el perfil y después hago la restauración del mismo la primera vez que entro me encuentro con las típicas preguntas del final de instalación de W11 (habilitar escritura, anuncios personalizados, etc...)

No encuentro una forma que me permita simplemente dejar el perfil exactamente como estaba a la hora de hacer el backup y ya estoy simplemente pensando que USMT no está pensado exactamente para eso.

¿Es posible o directamente me estoy chocando con una pared?

Gracias